# Importar projeto github no STS (Spring)

Tags: java, git, spring, github

Estou com dificuldades em importar um projeto com spring do github,sendo que consigo importar o projeto com exito quando é no eclipse oxygen na perspectiva java(Desktop).

---

**Procedimento utilizado de importação  :**

- Vou na pasta do meu sts que estão meus projetos
- Uso o comando init
- Uso o comando remote add origin servidor(Sincronizar meu git com o github)
- Uso o comando clone(pra baixar meu projeto do github)
- Import->General->Existing Projects in worckspace->Select root
  directory
- Vou na pasta aonde clonei o projeto

  ***ERRO***

> No projects are found to import

[Projeto que gostaria de baixar](https://github.com/acenelio/cursomc/tree/679a16a2fb3203a4bd479291a64bf1f893329359)

Comment: quais a configurações do projeto? ele é um projeto eclipse? é um projeto maven? gradle?

Comment: Eu consegui resolver tinha me esquecido de fechar a pergunta,tinha que importar como maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não estava importanto ,pois é um projeto Maven ou seja tem que importar como Maven
->Existing Maven Projects

Comment: Valeu Felipe!!!